# What's the difference between Charging, Official Charger, and USB Charger profiles in sys-clk manager?

Tags: nintendo-switch, homebrew

In the Nintendo Switch homebrew overclocking application [sys-clk](https://github.com/retronx-team/sys-clk), you can set different clock speeds based on 5 power profiles: Docked, Handheld, Charging, Official Charger, and USB Charger.

Docked and Undocked seem self explanatory, but the three charging profiles confuse me. I assumed the Official Charger profile would only be used when connected to Nintendo's official Switch charger, but it also gets applied when using my Lenovo-branded laptop charger.

What's the difference between the Charging, Official Charger, and USB Charger profiles in sys-clk? Why is the Official Charger profile applied when I use my laptop charger?

[image: sys-clk manager "Official Charger" progile while connected to a Lenovo laptop charger]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/retronx-team/sys-clk/blob/dcd0d5d34dbc2d57b5caade31b92c45ca2c48450/sysmodule/src/clocks.cpp#L203) for sys-clk seems to indicate that `SysClkProfile_HandheldChargingOfficial` is returned if `PsmChargerType chargerType` is equal to `PsmChargerType_EnoughPower`

```
if(chargerType == PsmChargerType_EnoughPower)
{
   return SysClkProfile_HandheldChargingOfficial;
}
```

If `chargerType` equals `PsmChargerType_LowPower`, it returns `SysClkProfile_HandheldChargingUSB`.  If it is neither of these, it will return `SysClkProfile_Handheld`.

[`PsmChargerType` is an enum](https://switchbrew.github.io/libnx/psm_8h.html#a950035b62563a7469af439b38948ce82) that contains 4 different members, one for unconnected, one for low power, one for enough power, and not supported.

If you look at [this source file](https://github.com/retronx-team/sys-clk/blob/6edada8fc2de2a7edbd542276f0243825bb81d7d/common/include/sysclk/clocks.h#L100), it returns what I believe is the text seen in this interface.  If the `profile` is `SysClkProfile_HandheldChargingOfficial` it will return "Official Charger", which after looking at the other code, it simply means you have "enough power" (presumably "enough power" means you have an adequate amount of power to overclock, etc.).

As far as I can tell in the code, there is no place where some variable or *some thing* is set to `SysClkProfile_HandheldCharging`.  The only thing I can see in the code that actually uses this to set something is [this `if` check](https://github.com/retronx-team/sys-clk/blob/dcd0d5d34dbc2d57b5caade31b92c45ca2c48450/sysmodule/src/clocks.cpp#L281) that checks if the `profile` is less than `SysClkProfile_HandheldCharging`, and if it is, it returns `SYSCLK_GPU_HANDHELD_MAX_HZ` which seems like some sort of limiter.

Thus, I believe "Official Charger" will be the profile displayed if your Switch is being charged by a charger that meets or exceeds the power rating of Nintendo's official power supply.  Anything lower will display "USB Charger" (aside from being docked or not charging at all).

Comment: I would also be careful with any unofficial power supplies.  I think most devices now a days can determine whether or not a power supply is too much for it to handle to protect itself, but I don't know if the Switch does (I would imagine it does).  I am also guessing your Lenovo power supply is variable (i.e. it can output different amounts of voltages at different amps to achieve a theoretical maximum wattage).

Comment: Any idea how much power is considered "enough power" for an official charger?

Comment: You're likely correct about `HandheldCharging` being a fallback. The [sys-clk readme](https://github.com/retronx-team/sys-clk#config) calls it a "*Non specific charging config*"

Comment: @Stevoisiak do you have an official Nintendo power supply? It should be listed on it. This third party one on Amazon has the specs listed https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvjR5.jpg

Comment: @Stevoisiak TV-mode profile is 15v 2.6A, 39W. Which you can now find on beefier powerbanks or on some laptop chargers (purpose-built chargers often have just one high voltage profile).
Out of that only about half is actually used while gaming on heavier games (source: my talkative power bank told me so), rest is "reserved" for charging and powering connected USB devices but Switch won't enter TV-mode if power supply doesn't report at least 2.6A.